# Please explain why I have a Question Ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have asked 3 questions, with votes of 16, 5 and 0, one Answer, vote 0. No deleted Questions. What have I done to cause a Question Ban? I didn't see anything by looking at the provided Help.

Edit: It looks like I have one "removed" question. Seems a bit severe, don't you think? In Baseball, you get 3 strikes. You guys play rough!

Another edit: **Why don't you let me see more of my own history of closed and deleted questions?** Apparently other people can see them, so show this data to me as well! I don't memorize my activity here over the last year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've asked 10 questions:

- [Please give some references for examples of class hierarchies](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/292122/please-give-some-references-for-examples-of-class-hierarchies) (score of -5, closed and deleted)
- [Demonstrate Polymorphism with Tic Tac Toe where students submit player code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/292152/demonstrate-polymorphism-with-tic-tac-toe-where-students-submit-player-code) (score of 0, closed and deleted)
- [Why is 12-based indexing not more common?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/302527/why-is-12-based-indexing-not-more-common) (score of -3, closed and deleted)
- [How to explain the mystery of programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307200/how-to-explain-the-mystery-of-programming) (score of -4, closed and deleted)
- [How to decide what instance variables to have in a class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309181/how-to-decide-what-instance-variables-to-have-in-a-class) (score of 1)
- [I think fan-in fan-out is backward, please explain](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/308079/i-think-fan-in-fan-out-is-backward-please-explain) (score of -3, closed and deleted)
- [Should “default constructor” mean the compiler-generated one and “no-argument constructor” mean one you create?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310359/should-default-constructor-mean-the-compiler-generated-one-and-no-argument-co) (score of 0)
- [I need a real-world example of a class to demonstrate consistent state](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310789/i-need-a-real-world-example-of-a-class-to-demonstrate-consistent-state) (score of -6, closed and deleted)
- [Should <= and >= be avoided when using integers, such as in a For loop?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/313143/should-and-be-avoided-when-using-integers-such-as-in-a-for-loop) (score of 16, closed)
- [Why are Update statements in SQL called Queries?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/314946/why-are-update-statements-in-sql-called-queries) (score of 0, closed and deleted)

Your net score on questions is negative and you have more closed and deleted questions than open questions. You've had a lot more than 3 strikes to learn about what is considered a good question for this community. It seems like a question block is in order, to me.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I wish that the UI would not hide these facts from me. When I look at my profile, I do not see all of that history. Not sure how you are seeing it, but shouldn't I? Maybe I could learn if the feedback was not hidden. I am active on many sites, and I do not keep these facts in my head. Some of my questions were tongue in cheek, some were peeves. Maybe some were uninformed. But I am not a malicious person, so just show the data and I can see for myself! **I teach programming, so I am trying to learn so I can teach others. My dumb questions could save you more.**

Comment: @nocomprende You could raise issues on Meta Stack Exchange, but I believe other similar requests have been declined. Prior to being blocked from asking new questions, you should have encountered warnings that you were approaching a question block. There's not much that can be done if those warnings are ignored.

Comment: But YOU can see my list of deleted questions. Should I not be able to also? This seems rather obvious to me. And, say I get a warning here and there, it goes away and I move along. I am not keeping a running score of my faults, which apparently you are. Don't faults expire eventually? If not, I still say that you play rough. I wish I could see a timeline of this activity. It is likely that these things were spread out over time and not frequent. I do other things with my time you know. This site and Christianity (ironically) are the only ones that question-banned me. That should say something.

Comment: @nocomprende Moderators can see the questions in a person's profile. Stack Exchange decided to only show recent questions that were deleted (where recent is something like 60 or 90 days from the time they were posted) to the posting user. The question block system, which is a fully automated process that can't be overridden, keeps track of your entire posting history. The block is also a black box - Stack Exchange doesn't say how they are computed or what causes them to expire, but there are some good indicators (like having a net negative score and deleted posts). (1 of 2)

Comment: I fully agree with your concerns, but you'll have to take them up on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/). I'd recommend searching, as there may already have been people who brought up these concerns. There's absolutely nothing anyone on Programmers can do to help you, though. The general advice is to (1) review your deleted questions and try to edit to make them better so they can be undeleted and reopened, if possible and (2) post good answers, since positive contributions to the community can help lift the block.

Comment: I looked at the list you provided for me, thank you. Here are the results: Off-Topic, Too Broad, Opinion-Based (this one was silly), OB (called for a discussion), Open (+1, 3 Answers), OB (1 answer which helped my understand a lot), Open (2 good Answers which helped me in my teaching),  OT, OB (but it got +16, 7 Answers - one with +36 and 2300 views in about one day. Someone thought it was worthwhile), and finally one I deleted, based on comments I got - See? I am learning! Overall, I don't see this as so bad. I just wish that I could see it for myself.